# How to connect to Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

Multiple values have been retrieved from the Azure portal and copied to the following file, e.g. A, B, C and D:

main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "A"
  client_id       = "B"
  client_secret   = "C"
  tenant_id       = "D"
}
```

Running `terraform apply`, resulted in:

```
Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Credentials for acessing the Azure Resource Manager API are likely to be 
incorrect, or the service principal does not have permission to use the Azure
Service Management API.
```

**Attempt to solve the issue**

Although `Windows Azure Management API` was selected and subsequently `Access Azure Service Management as organization users (preview)` was added the issue persisted after running `terraform apply` again.

**Second Attempt**

Following [the steps](http://www.thehyperadvisor.com/cloud-computing/terraform-your-azure-infrastructure/) from this tutorial resulted in the creation of a Virtual Network in the Classic Portal instead of the New one.

A [publish_settings file](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings) was downloaded and used in the following configuration snippet:

```
provider "azure" {
  publish_settings = "${file("file.publishsettings")}"
}

resource "azure_virtual_network" "default" {
  name = "vNet01"
  address_space = ["10.0.0.1/24"]
  location = "North Europe"
  subnet {
  name = "Subnet1"
  address_prefix = "10.0.0.1/25"
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your debug/trace logs  ,  use TF_LOG=trace if you are not on windows platform.  If you are I cannot help. the  `azurerm` provider needs to be used instead of the legacy one.  You also have to enable automated deployment rights (needs to be done in the gui).  Then Terraform will be able to connect.

Comment: @030 You need create a service principle, then use it to connect Azure. Please refer to this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/).